# LocalStorage set property 'innerHTML' of null. Tried solution with window.onload

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a javascript that tries to get the information from the localStorage. Either i haven't fully understood window.onload or something else is faulty.

Thanks in advance!

onClickJs.js

```
function onClickLight() {
        alert("OnClick Log " + window.onload);

        window.onload = function (){
            var statusPub = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("statusPub");
            console.log(statusPub);

        }
```

index.jsp

```
<script>
        function load() {
            console.log("load event detected!");
        }
        window.onload = load;

    </script>

    <button type="lightButton" onclick="onClickLight()">Light</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you click the button, the `window` `load` event has **already** fired. So assigning a function to `window.onload` at that point is useless, the function will never be called.

If you want to do the work that function is doing, just...do it:

```
function onClickLight() {
    var statusPub = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("statusPub");
    console.log(statusPub);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem with that is that i still get the "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" problem. Then there is probably something else that is spooky. 

ive checked if the LocalStorage contains what i try to get and it does.

Comment: @AlbinÅberg: That tells you that as of when that code runs, there is no element with `id="result"` anywhere on the page.

Comment: Another question then:
how do i get the element with id="result" from onClickJs.js to my index.jsp?

Comment: @AlbinÅberg: I don't understand the question. Your HTML (in the JSP) should define the element, e.g., `<div id='result"></div>` or similar. Then your `onClickLight` function will be able to find it.

Comment: That answers my question, im quite new to web applications. 
You've been really helpful, thanks for the help!